# Get bug:"Field tdlRepo in com.example.demo.restController required a bean of type 'com.example.demo.tdlRepo' that could not be found."

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

This is the file where i got bug

```
@RestController
public class restController {
    @Autowired
    tdlRepo tdlRepo;
    @GetMapping("Hello/{name}")
    public String getName(@PathVariable String name){
        return "Hello" + name;
    }

    @GetMapping("GetData")
    public List<ListtodoEntity> getData(){
        return tdlRepo.findAll();
    }
}
```

Completed error message:
Field tdlRepo in com.example.demo.restController required a bean of type 'com.example.demo.tdlRepo' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
- @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.example.demo.tdlRepo' in your configuration.

Here ways i tried:

1. Config DataSource in application.properties
2. Config  JPA in application.properties
3. Check dependency
4. Check annotations
   But not worked.
   Help me

Comment: can you share github project repository ? i`m going to help you

Comment: package com.example.demo;
import java.util.List;

@Repository
public interface tdlRepo extends JpaRepository<ListtodoEntity,Long> {
    public List<ListtodoEntity> findAll();
}

Comment: just update the question with main class, where we can see the packages import.

Comment: and rename your Repository interface from `tdlRepo` to `TdlRepo `

Comment: I don't know why but I renamed and it works. Thank you.

Comment: i wrote an answer, why it solved your problem, just check and let me know if it was helpfully.

Comment: It 's helpful. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that the main problem would be a position of your main class in your project, so from what I see in your classes your main class should be located in the

```
com.example
```

not

```
com.example.demo.something
```

The reason for that is that Spring will scan all subpackages starting from the main class current position, so if it is in `com.example.demo` it will scan all subpackages which are `com.example.demo, com.example.service, com.example.utility`

If you do not want to move your main class you can simply add additional attributes to your `@SpringBootApplication` where you will mention all packages where your beans are defined
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-component-scanning

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages={"com.example.demo","com.example.service","com.example.utility"})
```

***But I would suggest that you simply move your main class to the package upwards.***

Next what you need is 3 lines in your application.properties

```
#
# JDBC properties
#
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database_name
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=rootpassword
```

And the last thing is the list of dependencies in your pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Also constructor injection would be a better choice than field injection in your constructor

```
@RestController
public class restController {

    TdlRepo tdlRepo;

    @Autowired
    restController(TdlRepo theTdlRepo) {
        tdlRepo=theTdlRepo;
    }

    @GetMapping("Hello/{name}")
    public String getName(@PathVariable String name){
        return "Hello" + name;
    }

    @GetMapping("GetData")
    public List<ListtodoEntity> getData(){
        return tdlRepo.findAll();
    }
}
```

Please keep in mind that I named repository interface with a capital **T**.
And keep in mind that you do not need any annotations in your interface like  `@Repository`

```
public interface TdlRepo extends JpaRepository<ListtodoEntity, Long>{}
```

is enough. ( again capital **T** )

After all of these changes make sure that you refresh your project's dependencies with

```
Maven > Reload ( IntelliJ )

Maven > Update Project > Force Update of Snapshots/Releases > Ok ( Eclipse )
```

Comment: I tried all above but not worked

Comment: Can you share your git then or at least provide more code with packages of all of your classes and also include your project structure?

Comment: Thank you. I rename the Repository and it work. Can you tell me why ???

Comment: If the only issue was renaming of the repository then I assume that IntelliJ or whichever IDE you are using was complaining about the naming convention, because it looked at your repository as a field instead of as an interface. That is why it is always good practice to have all your classes and interfaces starting with a capital letter.

Comment: I don't know why but I renamed the Repository from tplRepo to TdlRepo and it works. Thank you.

Comment: I wrote on top of your constructor with a capital letter for your TdlRepo, you could have just copied it. It is bad practice to name your classes/interfaces with a lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

**In Java, classes, interfaces and enums should all be written in Pascal case.**

**To name a bean, Spring uses the class name and converts the first letter to lowercase.**

More information about naming convention of `Beans` in Spring you can read here:
[Bean-Name](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.2.3.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-beanname)